# Identifying recurring process running on EC2 Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, process, disk

Our AWS account has a running EC2 instance - we are unsure what it's used for. The monitoring metrics for this instance appears to have some recurring CPU utilisation and credit usage (see below screenshots – spikes are for the same time each day).

[image: EC2 Monitoring Metrics]

The person who created the instance (which has a private key-pair) has left the company (key-pair obviously lost). It does have an EBS volume as its root storage device – I therefore created a snapshot of this and mounted it to a new EC2 instance. When accessing this I can’t see anything in it’s crontab – is there anything else that would account for the recurring usage stats for this instance? ..Is it possible the spikes in CPU utilisation and credit usage are just for monitoring its usage?

Comment: Those CPU spikes are rather small -- going up to `0.26%`, which is effectively nothing. The answer is simple -- Stop the instance and see if anyone complains!

Comment: Totally agree that they're minimal (and with stopping the instance) - but would be good to know given they're consistency each day. Cheers nonetheless

Comment: THe spikes though very minimal, seems like appearing in set interval. Maybe you can note the time difference in the spikes & during next few spikes do a htop or top command to see what exactly is causing it? You can use SSM to run the command so no need for key pair also. 

Monitoring does not usually cause spikes in CPU. It's more to memory from what few monitoring services I have used.

Comment: cheers - they are on a 24hr interval so will try your suggestion